# How can I detect when I'm done creating directories recursively with Kotlin Coroutines?

Tags: android, kotlin, recursion, google-drive-api, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to download an entire directory from Google Drive and store it locally on my Android device. My process for doing this involves downloading all the directory info first, and then crawling through the hierarchy recursively (starting at the root directory), creating the subdirectories as I go. The below recursive method accomplishes this correctly.

The problem is this: I have no way of knowing when this method completes, since I don't know of any proper stop condition. I know that once the last coroutine completes it will be done, but I can't figure out how to track when they're all done.

Things I've tried:

1. Incrementing/decrementing a counter for every coroutine I've started and checking when the counter reaches zero. This didn't work reliably.
2. Tracking all the coroutines through their Jobs. This seemed promising but I couldn't figure out how to make it work.
3. Not using coroutines at all for the recursive calls. This works but makes the operation take about twice as long.

Any help would be appreciated. And if I'm going about this the wrong way, I'd love to be set straight. Thanks!

My recursive method:

```
// directoryBeingBuilt starts as the root directory
private suspend fun createDirectoryStructure(directoryBeingBuiltId: String, directoryBeingBuiltUri: Uri) {

    // Create subdirectories for all children of directoryBeingBuilt.
    directoryMap[directoryBeingBuiltId]?.forEach { childDirectory ->

        // Create a directory for each childDirectory and set its Uri in directoryMap.
        val currentSubdirectoryUri = getOrCreateDirectory(directoryBeingBuiltUri, childDirectory.directoryName)!!
        childDirectory.directoryUri = currentSubdirectoryUri

        // Set the subdirectory we just built as directoryBeingBuilt and re-run this recursively.
        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
            createDirectoryStructure(childDirectory.directoryId, currentSubdirectoryUri)
        }
    }
}
```

How I'm initially calling the recursive method:

```
withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
    createDirectoryStructure(googleDriveRootDirectoryId.data, backupDirectoryUri)
    // I need to call some other method here only once the recursive method is done
}
```

`directoryMap` is a `Map` whose key = parent directory id and value = list of immediate subdirectories inside the parent directory:

```
private val directoryMap: MutableMap<String, List<DirectoryInfoContainer>> = mutableMapOf()
```

`DirectoryInfoContainer`:

```
data class DirectoryInfoContainer(val directoryId: String, val directoryName: String, var directoryUri: Uri?)
```

`getOrCreateDirectory()` method:

```
private suspend fun getOrCreateDirectory(parentUri: Uri, name: String): Uri? = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    DocumentsContract.createDocument(
        requireActivity().contentResolver, parentUri, DocumentsContract.Document.MIME_TYPE_DIR, name
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test this. Just an idea. Wrap your parallel work in `coroutineScope` so the suspend function won't return until all the inner jobs are finished.

Also, your suspend function is improper because it is marked suspend but calls blocking functions without wrapping them in `withContext`. This forces you to wrap calls to this function with an IO dispatcher, which defeats the purpose of marking it `suspend` and also breaks the convention for `suspend` functions.

But I could be wrong. Maybe `getOrCreateDirectory()` is a properly composed suspend function that internally delegates to an appropriate dispatcher. But if that's the case, you shouldn't have to specify the IO dispatcher when you launch coroutines that call this function. A proper suspend function can always be safely called from any dispatcher, because it's supposed to actually suspend and not block.

In the code below I'm assuming `getOrCreateDirectory` is a suspend function that wraps its blocking work in `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`.

```
private suspend fun createDirectoryStructure(directoryBeingBuiltId: String, directoryBeingBuiltUri: Uri) {
    coroutineScope {
        // Create subdirectories for all children of directoryBeingBuilt.
        directoryMap[directoryBeingBuiltId]?.forEach { childDirectory ->
    
            // Create a directory for each childDirectory and set its Uri in directoryMap.
            val currentSubdirectoryUri = getOrCreateDirectory(directoryBeingBuiltUri, childDirectory.directoryName)!!
            childDirectory.directoryUri = currentSubdirectoryUri
    
            // Set the subdirectory we just built as directoryBeingBuilt and re-run this recursively.
            launch {
                createDirectoryStructure(childDirectory.directoryId, currentSubdirectoryUri)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So now if you call this function in a suspend function (without needing to wrap it in `withContext`!), it will suspend until all those directories are created or an IOException is thrown.

Comment: Thanks you so much for the help! You have no idea what that means to me. With your changes, I am indeed getting the intended outcome. I only have one more concern: the moment I mark `getOrCreateDirectory()` as a suspend function, I get the warning "inappropriate blocking method call" for the `createDocument()` call (I've edited the OP to include this method). Should I ignore this warning? The operation seems to complete slightly faster with it marked as a suspend function.

Comment: Can edit your question to show what your `getOrCreateDirectory()` function looks like? There are occasional false positives for that warning.

Comment: I added it to the very bottom of the post. It's really just calling `DocumentsContract.createDocument()`.

Comment: Looks like a false positive that you can ignore since you wrapped it in `withContext`.